# netlink sequence numbers out of sequence

Tags: go, wifi, netlink

I'm using the [`netlink`](https://github.com/mdlayher/netlink) and [`genetlink`](https://github.com/mdlayher/genetlink) Go packages to write a utility to interact with the `MAC80211_HWSIM` netlink family functions. It's working well ... almost.

I'm finding that if I do a `GET_RADIO` call, the next call into the family fails to validate because the sequence number of the response doesn't match that of the request.  Specifically, the pattern I see is

```
GET_RADIO request:  seq=655
GET_RADIO response: seq=655
DEL_RADIO request:  seq=656
DEL_RADIO response: seq=655
```

It doesn't matter which command I issue after `GET_RADIO`, this same pattern shows up. If `GET_RADIO` isn't in the mix, then the sequence numbers are exactly as expected.

There's an existing command written in C, using `libnl` and `libgenl`, which I modified to run more than one command. As best I can tell, that implementation does a very similar thing, but doesn't have the issue with the sequence numbers, so I'm disinclined to think the problem lies with the kernel module. But strace clearly shows that the kernel is responding with an out-of-sequence number (please forgive the excessive side-scrolling):

```
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_GENERIC) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=18357, nl_groups=00000000}, [112->12]) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=40, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST, seq=2596996163, pid=18357}, "\3\1\0\0\23\0\2\0MAC80211_HWSIM\0\0"}, iov_len=40}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 40
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=112->12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=224, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=2596996163, pid=18357}, "\1\2\0\0\23\0\2\0MAC80211_HWSIM\0\0\6\0\1\0\31\0\0\0"...}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=0}}], iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_PEEK) = 224
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=112->12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=224, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=2596996163, pid=18357}, "\1\2\0\0\23\0\2\0MAC80211_HWSIM\0\0\6\0\1\0\31\0\0\0"...}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=0}}], iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 224
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=28, type=0x19 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ACK, seq=2596996164, pid=18357}, "\6\1\0\0\10\0\n\0T\0\0\0"}, iov_len=28}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 28
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=112->12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=48, type=0x19 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=2596996164, pid=18357}, "\6\1\0\0\10\0\n\0T\0\0\0\10\0\t\0\1\0\0\0\t\0\21\0phy84\0\0\0"}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=0}}], iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_PEEK) = 48
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=112->12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=48, type=0x19 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=2596996164, pid=18357}, "\6\1\0\0\10\0\n\0T\0\0\0\10\0\t\0\1\0\0\0\t\0\21\0phy84\0\0\0"}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=0}}], iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 48
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=28, type=0x19 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ACK, seq=2596996165, pid=18357}, "\5\1\0\0\10\0\n\0T\0\0\0"}, iov_len=28}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 28
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=112->12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=36, type=NLMSG_ERROR, flags=0, seq=2596996164, pid=18357}, "\0\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\31\0\5\0D\4\313\232\265G\0\0"}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=0}}], iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_PEEK) = 36
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=112->12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=36, type=NLMSG_ERROR, flags=0, seq=2596996164, pid=18357}, "\0\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\31\0\5\0D\4\313\232\265G\0\0"}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=0}}], iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
close(3)                                = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Note that there are two `recvmsg()` calls for each `sendmsg()` because the first one simply does a `MSG_PEEK` to see if an answer is available.  Of the three sets of requests and responses, the first (sequence ...163) is simply getting the family information.  The second (sequence 164) is doing the `GET_RADIO` (`\6`) call, and the third is the one with the out-of-sequence response: this `DEL_RADIO` (`\5`) call sends a message with a ...165 sequence number, but the response that comes back, otherwise well-formed, has a sequence number matching the previous command: ...164.

Because this is Go, there are multiple threads active at once, but all the calls in the strace output above are from the same thread. The only calls missing from the trace are those to `futex()`.

The C version, because it uses the callback mechanisms provided by `libnl` and `libgenl`, does process the response in a different thread than the request came from.  The request trace:

```
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_GENERIC) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [32768], 4) = 0
getpid()                                = 21338
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=-1300212902, nl_groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=-1300212902, nl_groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=20, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ACK|0x300, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\3\1\0\0"}, iov_len=20}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 20
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=116, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\1\2\0\0\v\0\2\0nlctrl\0\0\6\0\1\0\20\0\0\0\10\0\3\0\2\0\0\0"...}, {{len=96, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\1\2\0\0\16\0\2\0VFS_DQUOT\0\0\0\6\0\1\0\21\0\0\0\10\0\3\0"...}, {{len=104, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\1\2\0\0\17\0\2\0acpi_event\0\0\6\0\1\0\23\0\0\0\10\0\3\0"...}, {{len=108, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\1\2\0\0\22\0\2\0thermal_event\0\0\0\6\0\1\0\24\0\0\0"...}, {{len=112, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\1\2\0\0\20\0\2\0tcp_metrics\0\6\0\1\0\25\0\0\0\10\0\3\0"...}, {{len=112, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\1\2\0\0\16\0\2\0TASKSTATS\0\0\0\6\0\1\0\26\0\0\0\10\0\3\0"...}, {{len=2076, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\1\2\0\0\f\0\2\0nl80211\0\6\0\1\0\30\0\0\0\10\0\3\0\1\0\0\0"...}, {{len=224, type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\1\2\0\0\23\0\2\0MAC80211_HWSIM\0\0\6\0\1\0\31\0\0\0"...}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=0}}], iov_len=16384}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 2948
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=20, type=NLMSG_DONE, flags=NLM_F_MULTI, seq=1530817156, pid=2994754394}, "\0\0\0\0"}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=65542}}], iov_len=16384}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 20
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fdb752ce000
mprotect(0x7fdb752ce000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fdb75acdff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fdb75ace9d0, tls=0x7fdb75ace700, child_tidptr=0x7fdb75ace9d0) = 21339
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=28, type=0x19 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ACK, seq=1530817157, pid=2994754394}, "\6\1\0\0\10\0\n\0_\0\0\0"}, iov_len=28}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 28
nanosleep({tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffff64ac200) = 0
write(1, "Deleting radio with id '95'...\n", 31) = 31
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=28, type=0x19 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ACK, seq=1530817158, pid=2994754394}, "\5\1\0\0\10\0\n\0_\0\0\0"}, iov_len=28}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 28
nanosleep({tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0},  <unfinished ...>) = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

and the response trace:

```
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=48, type=0x19 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=1530817157, pid=2994754394}, "\6\1\0\0\10\0\n\0_\0\0\0\10\0\t\0\1\0\0\0\t\0\21\0phy95\0\0\0"}, {{len=0, type=0 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=0, seq=0, pid=0}}], iov_len=16384}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 48
epoll_wait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=3, u64=3}}], 32, -1) = 1
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=36, type=NLMSG_ERROR, flags=0, seq=1530817157, pid=2994754394}, "\0\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\31\0\5\0\205j>[ZS\200\262"}, {{len=1114121, type=0x6870 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ECHO|NLM_F_DUMP_INTR|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED|0x3940, seq=53, pid=0}, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"...}], iov_len=16384}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "new SSID defined to interface 95"..., 33) = 33
epoll_wait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=3, u64=3}}], 32, -1) = 1
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{{len=36, type=NLMSG_ERROR, flags=0, seq=1530817158, pid=2994754394}, "\0\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\31\0\5\0\206j>[ZS\200\262"}, {{len=1114121, type=0x6870 /* NLMSG_??? */, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ECHO|NLM_F_DUMP_INTR|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED|0x3940, seq=53, pid=0}, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"...}], iov_len=16384}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
write(1, "Successfully deleted device with"..., 39) = 39
exit_group(0)                                       = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The only thing that seems relevant to me (other than the threading structure) is that it uses different flags (`NLM_F_DUMP_INTR|NLM_F_DUMP_FILTERED` in the C code, `0` in the Go code).

I'm not sure what other tools I can bring to bear on this, since I don't know how those sequence numbers are constructed. There didn't seem to me to be anything unusually wrong with the code in the kernel module, in the Go packages, or in my Go code, but there could always be a mismatch between the way an interface was supposed to be used and the way it actually was. Does this problem seem familiar to anyone, or does anyone have any thoughts on how to make progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why this situation occurs, but it appears the TL;DR fix is to read the next packet: it will have the same data with the correct sequence number.

I tried writing a program with a different [netlink package](https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink/), and discovered that while it had the same issue, it repeated the `recvmsg()` call when it runs into this situation.  The code that does that is here:

https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink/blob/a06dabf/nl/nl_linux.go#L425

The commit that introduced that code doesn't explain why this loop is correct, but emulating it in the other package takes care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue with the `NBD` netlink family.

In my case, I was using the same library you are using (`mdlayher/netlink`), and using the `netlink.Acknowledge` flag on some `Execute()` requests.

I figured out that the `netlink.Acknowledge` flag is only needed for cases where the device driver doesn't explicitly send a reply, but you want a reply anyway. If the driver already sends a reply but you set `netlink.Acknowledge`, then you'll get a "double reply", where both replies have the same sequence number. This causes the "sequence mismatch" error you're seeing, because the next time you call `recv()` (via `Execute()`), you'll first receive the ACK from the previous request., *then* receive the "real" reply to your request (this is why the "ignore mismatch and retry" approach works, as you noted in your answer).

My *guess* is that drivers will typically not send a reply if you are doing a "mutate" operation that doesn't return any state back to you, and so if you want an acknowledgement that the mutate was received, then you need to set the ACK flag. Something like a "query" / "get" operation would be expected to return a reply, so the ACK flag would typically not be needed in that case.

The only way to be certain whether the ACK flag is needed is to look at the driver source (e.g. the `torvalds/linux` repo on GitHub) and check whether the particular function that you are invoking in your `Execute()` request includes an explicit call to `genlmsg_reply`, e.g. here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/40f71e7cd3c6ac04293556ab0504a372393838ff/drivers/block/nbd.c#L2422